# Issue in Upgrading Http to Https in websocket flutter

Tags: flutter, http, ssl, websocket, https

I created websocket connection In flutter with **stomp dart client** package it will work perfectly by using the **http** protocol.but now the server is now upgraded to **https** I also change the base URL to https but it won't work "**is the problem is from frontend (flutter) side or not "**